# vulnerable webapp pentest challenge

Tags: php, penetration-test, shellcode

So I have this challenge in pentesting to get a shell on a vulnerable webapp. I am an authenticated user and I know that the vulnerable app is `kcfinder-2.51` which is a plugin for `ckeditor_3.6.4`.

I am trying to upload weevely shell, but the problem is that the server is configured to redirect everything to 404-page if it's a directory or if it's a wrong file.

Another problem is that the upload directory is unique to every user even a non-authenticated user has a different upload directory.

- How do I know which upload directory the shell is uploaded on?
- And if I upload a `.htaccess` file in that directory can I enable directory listing or change the config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the upload url, which was in the `browse.php` html page source

```
<script type="text/javascript">
....
browser.uploadURL = "http://host.com/files";
....
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do much more than enabling directory indexes with a `.htaccess` file. Take a look at my htshells project: https://github.com/wireghoul/htshells/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to find the correct url that will allow you to upload your payload, but you do not know the correct path.

In this case I would recommend a tool such a [dirbuster](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_DirBuster_Project). It will brute force directories (and file extensions) according to any wordlist you feed it (you can add the usernames/custom variables to a typical wordlist to be more accurate). You can also configure the tool to recursively check for files/directories.

p.s. This tool is built-in on Kali and has custom wordlists already loaded on Kali as well.